# In which scenario it is best to use the SGD optimizer

Tags: machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I am new to ML and going through that i found difficulty in choosing the optimizer there are lots of optimizer, but I am confused when to use the Stochastic Gradient Descent optimizer and Why?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding: the modern, sophisticated gradient descent algorithms like ADAM use more computational power than SGD.  They make trial moves before committing to a step down the gradient.  This extra sophistication is quite helpful when working with deeper neural network architectures.  Such architectures may have very complex loss hypersurfaces, with multiple saddle points and local minima.  ADAM and its relatives do a good job finding the solution in these situations.

If your model architectures are simpler, apparently that the extra effort is not worth it.  Stochastic gradient descent works well for simple models, and if you add Nesterov momentum and weight decay, you can often converge on a solution faster than you can with ADAM.

Another place that SGD is used is as a substitute for solving very large linear regressions by ordinary least-squares.  In theory, any invertible matrix can be solved exactly.  But it's entirely possible in the modern age to have a matrix inversion problem whose intermediate terms require more memory than you have in RAM.  In that case, SGD is the more practical way to solve the problem.